# Faulty Toshiba fan after clean

Tags: fan

Today my friend brought me the laptop of his dad for dust clean and format.(installed Lubuntu 15). The laptop was a Toshiba Satellite L300-2C4 2Gb ram and Pentium Dual-Core T4200 at 2.00 GHz!

After the cleaning i assembly it and push the power key to start! All good BUT the fan **starts** spinning and **stop** after 10 sec! I change ram slot ( one 2 gb dimm),now the fan **spins**, but i have **no screen signal**. Completly black! Change again, i have screen but, fan stop after 10 sec.

I clean-install ubuntu 14.04 thinking it might be a software problem but the same exaclty problem.

Any help guys? Any suggestion? What i must do?

Comment: Hold on a second. There is nothing wrong with a fan that stops spinning on a laptop!  On my laptop the fan only turns on when necessary, based on CPU load.  Try boot up into your OS and run some CPU-intensive app/game. See if the fan starts spinning then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you destroyed the magic dust that all computers require to operate  successfully.

Ok, seriously now, 
First,  LIGHTLY,  using one finger,  see if you can spin the fan easily.

It possible  that you accidentally pushed some dust into the bearings.

If not use canned air to carefully blow any dust off the fan.  Its better to use a vacuum cleaner designed for computers instead of canned air.

If possible, do not reassemble yet. Reboot and try again.

If still no working, disconnect the fan,  and with denatured NOT, REPEAT NOT RUBBING alcohol (as it contains oils) to clean the pins on the fan and the connections on the motherboard.  A pencil eraser can be used instead, but be careful of the new dust you'll make.

Also, a drop of lightweight oil on the fan bearings (be aware however that some have oilless bearings that you can't add oil to) isn't remiss.

As to the RAM issue, some motherboards need the RAM in the first slot to operate.

Comment: The fan can spin only by looking at it. With my pinky finger push it spins fine. Just from the nose exhale it spins!  I did the steps that you recommend but thanks man :D .

1)Also something i found out. If i open it and the fan does not start at first boot, after i restart the fan starts... 

2)Also at first boot, if i go to bios reset to defaults save and exit, the fan starts operating ...

Could it be a bios mulfuction?

P.S In this site is there a forum to ask cause many voted its off topic :/ 
"This question appears to be off-topic for this site."

Answer (score 0):

When using compressed air to clean a computer fan you must be careful to hold one of the fan blades firmly between the thumb and forefinger to prevent the fan from spinning too rapidly. Otherwise a strong blast of compressed air can cause mechanical damage to the fan. If you take your laptop to a computer repair shop and are advised to lubricate the fan's bearing, you should be aware that you are essentially buying time by doing this because this will frequently only improve the fan's performance temporarily, and if the problem reoccurs you will have to replace the fan anyway.